# Regex for matching a word with two ore more capital letters li

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter

I'm trying to filter out words with multiple capital letters in cyrillic like in this example in google sheets:

ПредметыПапкиВзаимодействий

I've tried this one: \w*[А-Я]\w*[А–Я]\w

But it's only showing acronyms like ЭДО, ЕГАИС, etc.

Could you suggest any solutions?

Comment: You probably want something like `[А-ЯЁ][^А-ЯЁ]*[А-ЯЁ]` or `[А-ЯЁ][^А-ЯЁ\s]*[А-ЯЁ]`. Where are you using the regex?

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I'm using it in google sheets Filter Condition -> Custom Formula field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
[А-ЯЁ][^А-ЯЁ]*[А-ЯЁ]
```

Or, if there can/should be no whitespaces between two capital letters you can use

```
[А-ЯЁ][^А-ЯЁ\s]*[А-ЯЁ]
```

*Details*:

- `[А-ЯЁ]` - uppercase Russian letters
- `[^А-ЯЁ\s]*` - any zero or more chars other than Russian uppercase letters and whitespace
- `[А-ЯЁ]`  - uppercase Russian letters